# Distribution smoothing and rising/falling probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Say I have a sequence of real numbers $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ where $a_i \geq 1$, and  $a_i \leq a_j$ if $i < j$.

Define $p(i) = \frac{a_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n a_j}$ and $p_\alpha(i) = \frac{a_i^\alpha}{\sum_{j=1}^n a_j^\alpha}$, where $0 < \alpha < 1$.

If we assume $a_i = i$, what is the first $i$ where $p(i) \geq p_\alpha(i)$? What if $a_i = c^i$ for some real number $c > 1$? What if $a_i = i^c$?

In other words: if smoothing is re-allocating mass from the more likely events to the less likely, what is the event whose probability remains unchanged or (if there is none that remains equal) where we first see a drop in probability.

Goal: I understand the overall *action* of smoothing but I'm curious if we can say more about the action of on some simple distributions without having to resort to numerical methods.

Comment: I suspect this might be analytically easier if you had a non-negative increasing function $f(x)$ on $[0,n]$  with $p(x)=f(x) / \int_0^n f(y) \,dy$ and $p_\alpha(x) = f(x)^\alpha/\int_0^n f(y)^\alpha\, dy$ and the answers may be similar if not the same

Comment: @Henry That allowed me to find the answers analytically for the continuous functions. I'll post an answer soon with some graphs to illustrate the correspondence between the series and the functions. Very nifty trick; does it have a name and conditions under which it works?